# How do I make mu functions stop from having an unitended effect when I call them in other functions?

Tags: c

I plan to use read_command in my later functions. How can I make it so that my read_command doesn't keep on printing "Enter a command:". I want to use this function in future if else statements.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    char read_command()
    {
        char command;
        char result;

        printf("Enter a command: ");
        scanf("%c", &command);
        if (command  == 'I' || command == 'i' || command == 'P' || command == 'p' || command == 'D' || command == 'd' || command == 'L' ||        command == 'l' || command == 'Q'|| command == 'q')

            result = command;
        else

            result = 'V';

        return result;

    }

    void print_music_lib()
    {
       if (read_command == 'P'|| read_command == 'p')
       {
          printf("Only prints when case is P or p");
       }
    }



  void evaluate_command()
  {


       while (true)

       {
           char valid_command = read_command();
           scanf("%c", &valid_command);
           switch(valid_command)

           {
               case 'I':
               case 'i':
                     printf("This is the letter I or i\n");
               case 'P':
               case 'p':
                     printf("This is the letter P or p\n");
               case 'D':
               case 'd':
                     printf("This is the letter D or d\n");
               case 'L':
               case 'l':
                     printf("This is the letter L or l\n");
               case 'Q':
               case 'q':

                     printf("This is the letter Q or q\n");
            //on_quit = valid_command;

    }
    if (valid_command == 'Q' || valid_command == 'q')
         break;
    //return on_quit;
    }
}



   int main()
   {
       read_command();
       //printf("%c", read_command());
       evaluate_command();

       return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically only have two solutions:

1. Don't print the prompt inside the function, instead print it in the calling function, before calling `read_command`.
2. Add a boolean argument that tells the function if the prompt should be printed or not.

---

By the way, you have a logical error (besides the syntax error) in the code you show: When you do

```
if (read_command() == 'P'|| read_command() == 'p')
```

you are actually reading input *twice*, and of course forcing the user to write input twice. Instead you should store the result in a variable and check the variable instead:

```
char result = read_command();
if (result == 'p' || result == 'P') { ... }
```

This will, incidentally, also solve the problem with the prompting: One call, one prompt.

Comment: since most people will enter the letter in lower case, (as the OP probably did while testing), most of the time only a single command will be read. This is a nice example of hidden bugs that won't be caught if you don't design the test suite.
For the rest: solution 1 is clearly the preferred solution, as a function should do only one thing.

Comment: Can we know *calling function* name in the *called function*?

Comment: @rootkea No, this is not possible unless you add another function argument where you pass the name of the calling function. (Theoretically you can use the stack to figure the caller out, but this is more or less a hack).

Comment: @jofel I am interested in stack probing trick. Any pointers, references?

Comment: @rootkea See e.g. http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2010/09/stack-unwinding-stack-trace-with-gcc/ or learn assembler.